# Clean way to initialize an arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I want an Arraylist in Java, which I want to fill with `10`'s

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(100);
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    list.add(10);
}
```

I'm going to have to initialize a lot of Arraylists, so I was wondering if there is there a clean way to do this without a `for` loop?

Comment: Your list will be empty! And if it's size wasn't 0, you would get infinite loop

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [Collections.nCopies](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#nCopies%28int,%20T%29):

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(Collections.nCopies(100, 10));
```

This will initialize `list` with 100 10's.

Answer (score 2):

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(100);
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) 
{
    list.add(10);
}
```

`list.size()` will be 0 here, so this is why your code does not work.  `size` keeps track of how many elements are currently in the list, not the capacity.

If you want the `ArrayList` to be initialized with all 10s, you can use:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(Collections.nCopies(100, 10));
```

Edit:
 You said later that you didn't want a `for` loop, but to fix your code, just replace `list.size()` with 100.

Comment: huh, how does `for(int i=0; i < 100; i++)` generate an infinite loop?